# GET request returns values POST doesn't

Tags: java, android, database, api, android-volley

I'm making an app with some user interaction.
For this project I've created a method.

If I make a GET request* I get my values.
However if I make a POST request I get no values.
Does anyone know why this is?

I use POST because I'll be transmitting Base64 encoded images.
Does anyone know a solution or how I should tackle this problem?

Thanks

```
public void getUserFromId(Integer id, final VolleyCallBack volleyCallBack) {
    String requestURL = SUBMIT_URL + "getUserFromId/"+ id;
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context).add(
            new JsonArrayRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET*,
                    requestURL,
                    null,
                    response -> {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        if (response.length() > 0) {
                            try {
                                userFromId = new User(
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).getInt("idUser"),
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userName") + "",
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userPassword") + "",
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userProfilePicture") + "",
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userBirthday") + "",
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userGender") + "",
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userLink") + "",
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userLocation") + "",
                                        response.getJSONObject(0).get("userEmail") + ""
                                );

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            volleyCallBack.onSuccess();
                        }
                        else volleyCallBack.onFail();
                    },
                    e -> Log.d("DB: ", e.getMessage(), e)
            ));
}
```

Comment: You cannot just change a get request in a post request usually. Its the server who determines if you have to use a get or post or can use both.

Comment: If I use a small GET it work. If I user a big GET it doesn't work. If I use small POST it doesn't work. If I user big POST it doesn't work. I don't know. Tomorrow is the deadline. I'm f*cked.

Comment: I dont see you put an encoded image in a get request. So what is it that you call big? A querystring cannot be bigger then a few KB.

Comment: I found the error. If you make a POST request you don't put the parameters into the url but pass it as a static with an override function getParams